# Which book and chapter match with episode 8 season 3 from Game of Thrones TV Series?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

I first started watching the TV show and after some time I learned that waiting for the next episode/season is torture to me, so after having completely watched the first two seasons I decided to read the books so I don't need to wait a week or longer to find out what happens next.

As I started reading the books I faced another difficulty, namely that I have to read through 2000+ pages while roughly knowing what will happen on these pages, which also makes the reading far less enjoyable. Though I normally prefer not leaving out, I wanted to ask if anyone could tell me where in the books I have to "jump in" to read on approximately from where the current episode (season 3 ep. 8 at the moment of writing) has ended.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I wish I could trade places with you and read the books for the first time again.

Answer (score 12):

I would offer to say that you *not* jump ahead. Sure the major events are more or less the same in the book and the series, but they are *not* identical. Also, the books are far more nuanced and character rich than the TV series is. If you do jump ahead you'll find yourself more confused than relieved. Just off the top of my head you'll start wondering who the heck Asha is, or Jeyne Westerling, or Strong Belwas ... etc. You'll find yourself slogging through a several dozen new characters (or characterizations) just to get by. It's doable with a bit of Googling, but I really do advise you to read the books from the beginning. You'll get a much better understanding of the history of Westeros that led to the current crisis, and a deeper outlook into the motivations of the characters.

Edited to add, there are several extremely interesting and cool scenes that had to be cut out of the TV series due to budget or time constraints. The famous Tower of Joy comes to mind. If you skip the books you miss out on some very important events that get mentioned later on.

Comment: +1 Also, don't forget the Winterfell siege and almost all the fights from A Clash of Kings (season 2 in the series). Almost none of the true history of Westeros is in the series, and some major events and happenings have been changed, which really spoils the whole story from the books series itself.

Comment: @Secko - Ah yes! I was soooo disappointed that they made Tyrion *sleep* through the battle of the Greenfork.

Answer (score 1):

A Storm of Swords Chapter 28. This is the day of Sansa's Wedding in the books (the episode spans more than one chapter in the books but this chapter should be fine. If needs be go one back.) Hope this makes your reading easier.